# CloudQueue GetMessage vs GetMessages

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I wonder what is  the overhead of getting the messages one by one using the GetMessage vs GetMessages? 
Should I always use GetMessages(32) and will it have any advantage over GetMessage()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have 32 messages in your queue and your intent is to get all messages in the queue, if you call GetMessage() you would need to make 32 calls to get all messages thus 32 API transactions where as if you call GetMessages(32) you would make just one call to get all messages thus just 1 transaction.

More than that, I think it depends on your application. For example, I have been playing with this functionality where I decided that my application's worker role (let's call it "consumer") instance can process 4 messages at a time. In that case, for me it was better to fetch 4 messages from the queue using GetMessages(4) and making sure that the 4 messages processed by my consumer instances are invisible to other callers. If I had made use of GetMessage(), then I would have to make this call 4 times and if I made use of GetMessages(32), then my consumer instance would just sit on those additional 28 messages and other consumer instances would not get a chance to work on those messages.

Comment: Thanks, but did you measure the overhead of calling 4 times GetMessage instead of one GetMessages(4)? I wonder if there will be a real world difference.

Comment: I haven't done this. My guess is that the overhead would be the response size. You're getting more data out of storage system. Other thing I could think of is the processing time taken by Windows Azure which I would think would be negligible.

Comment: @user1662812 Real-world difference in terms of what? If you called it four times in a serial loop, you'd probably notice the extra latency, since it's 4 HTTP requests (round-trips to storage) instead of one. From within the same data center, I'd say you'd add 30-90ms of extra latency due to the extra calls to `GetMessage`. But in terms of throughput, I wouldn't expect a difference. In CPU time, it's probably more expensive to parse four XML responses than one. (There's more data, as Gaurav pointed out.)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, Calling GetMessages makes sense based on your application. If by design it's more efficient for me to process messages in batches then I should get them in batches (small messages, low overhead to process one of them) but instead if it takes 1-5 minutes to process one message then you are better off doing GetMessage but having multiple worker roles doing the work.

So, it depends